# Returning a value from controller to partial view using 'return PartialView(..)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project that requires me to achieve the following:

1. Make a selection from a drop down menu in a partial view
2. Pass the id of the selected value to the action method in my controller
3. Use that id to query the db to get a new value
4. Return and display that value in a text box on the same partial view

[image]

For example, if I choose a different fund then the fund code for that fund will display in the text box.

Here is the relevent code in my partial view.  What I'm trying to do here is either get a value from the model if it exists or get the default value from the query.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var qry = (from id in _db.myTable
            select new
            {
                id.Code,

            }).FirstOrDefault();

    _changedId = Model.Code ?? qry.Code;
}



<td><%: Html.DropDownListFor(fn1 => Model.Id, _val, new { @id = myId" } )%>
                </td>
                <td class="labels"> 
                    Value:
                </td>
                <td>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(fc => Model.Value, new { @Value= _changedId, @readonly = true }) %>
</td>
```

**NOTE:  I'm aware that this is not best practice for MVC but this is how the project was written.**

Here is the action method:

```
public ActionResult GetFundCode(MyModel fnc)
    {
        int fid = fnc.Id;

        var qry = (from tab in _db.AnotherTable
                     where tab.Id == fid
            select tab).FirstOrDefault();

        fnc.newCode = qry.Code;

        return PartialView("~/Views/TransactionCommonInputs/FromToFundSearchSelector.ascx",fnc);
    }
```

My action method does 'work' in that it return the correct value in the model 'fnc'. I get the new value and assign this in a page load section of the partial view posted above and again here:

```
_changedId = Model.fundCode ?? qryFundCode.FundCode;
```

Running through VS2010 debugger shows that the value returned from the controller to my partial view is correct.  That is when I hover over '_changedValue' it is assigned the value that I want:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(fc => Model.Value, new { @Value= _changedId, @readonly = true }) %>
</td>
```

However, the value displayed when I run the code reverts to a previous value.

I hope this is more understandable than my first post.

Comment: I'm confused trying to understand what you're trying to do. Can you post more details? Controller names, action names, PartialView names, etc. Guide us through it as if explaining it to someone that has never seen the code before (because we haven't).

Comment: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` in an ASP.NET MVC application? Seriously? And you are asking why this code isn't working.

Comment: As I said, "NOTE: I'm aware that this is not best practice for MVC but this is how the project was written.".  Are there any SO members who can offer some constructive advice?

Comment: Throw this away and start again using a proper MVC template.